# only rebuild part of page with callbacks

Tags: flutter, dart

I give two buttons to choose a gender to the user, and I want the uso can ,choose but when not only row rebuild, the gender value will update. I can do itthe  with provider but I know this can do with callbackfunctions. I read, I tried but I coldn't , in addition can you give me a sources about this to learn. If title is bad, feel free to change

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UserCreateView extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserCreateView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<UserCreateView> createState() => UserCreateViewState();
}

class UserCreateViewState extends State<UserCreateView> {
  bool? gender;

  void changeGender(bool genderChoose) {
    gender = genderChoose;
    setState(() {});
  }

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text('I dont want to be rebuild, fix it'),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      changeGender(true);
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: gender != true
                          ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 161, 207)
                          : const Color.fromARGB(255, 37, 131, 41),
                    ),
                    child: const Text(
                      'man',
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        changeGender(false);
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: gender == true
                            ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 161, 207)
                            : const Color.fromARGB(255, 37, 131, 41),
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        'woman',
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You like to rebuild only row?

Comment: I want to rebuild row, while rebuild row, I want to update gender

Comment: You can check `ValueNotifier` also included my answer snippet

Comment: I will check, thanks a lot, this is the perfect solution for me. just curious can we make this with callback functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ValueNotifier` with [`ValueListenableBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html) in this case.

```dart
class UserCreateView extends StatelessWidget {
  const UserCreateView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

    final ValueNotifier<bool?> gender = ValueNotifier(null);
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: Form(
          key: _formKey,
          child: Column(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: const Text('I dont want to be rebuild, fix it'),
              ),
              ValueListenableBuilder(
                valueListenable: gender,
                builder: (context, value, child) => Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        gender.value = true;
                      },
                      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        primary: gender.value != true
                            ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 161, 207)
                            : const Color.fromARGB(255, 37, 131, 41),
                      ),
                      child: const Text(
                        'man',
                      ),
                    ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                      child: ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          gender.value = false;
                        },
                        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                          primary: gender.value == true
                              ? const Color.fromARGB(255, 92, 161, 207)
                              : const Color.fromARGB(255, 37, 131, 41),
                        ),
                        child: const Text(
                          'woman',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two way in which you can solve this issue.

1. ValueNotifier and ValueListenableBuilder
   You can learn the working using code from here

https://medium.com/@avnishnishad/flutter-communication-between-widgets-using-valuenotifier-and-valuelistenablebuilder-b51ef627a58b

2. Streams and StreamBuilder:
   You may know about streams and streambuilder and you know what we can use this to rebuild only a widget and it's works very effeciently and is clean in comparison with value notifier

https://medium.com/@avnishnishad/flutter-understanding-the-stream-and-streambuilder-a2f8b69efa15

Comment: I can provide you the code for your question, but as per me, a developer should know how and why we are doing this that's why I am attaching two of my blogs.